Access external input with python
i'd like to read some dictionary i've externalized from my main python program.
i've added the following code to my main program named translate.py
g_DICTS = "/dictionaries"
g_dicts =  os.getcwd() + g_DICTS
sys.path.append(f"{g_dicts}")
import uxordre

Unfortunately, here's what i get :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user123/scripts/translate.py", line 247, in <module>
    import uxordre
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uxordre'

Tree looks like this :

Any idea? Thanks.

Is ./dictionaries/uxordre.py a file?

Why not just read it in as e.g. JSON, rather than trying to import it as Python?

Dont know JSON i'm afraid and i'm new to Python :/

Try with from dictionaries import uxordre.

The file needs to be named uxordre.py. It needs to contain Python code that assigns the dictionary you want.

Is the dictionaries directory really in the root folder of the filesystem? If not, /dictionaries should be the full path to the directory.

@Barmar, yes thats better. Thanks a lot

full path is obtained through os.getcwd() + "/dictionaries"

now i get :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uxordre.py'; 'uxordre' is not a package
This is how looks uxordre.py :
import re
ConvertCommand = {
'uxordre': [
{
'RegEx': re.compile( r'^(.?[$%]cmdlance%?\s+)($%%?)?[\/]uxordre(.exe)?(...)?\s+tsk=(\S+)\s+[mug]{2}=(\S+)\s+launchvar="([^"]?)"(.*)$', re.IGNORECASE ),
'Format': '%1%CmdCtm --order --folder %6% --manage %7% --variables "%8%"%9%',
},
]
}

You just got to:

rename your uxodre file to uxodre.py

Assuming you have created a my_dictionary variable in your uxodre.py module, you can access it from translate.py using something like this:
from dictionaries import uxordre as ux
imported_dictionary = ux.my_dictionary


